# Create Setup from more one project

Tags: .net, visual-c++, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have project which is combination of 3  projects.one project is main and other are for plugin etc.Project is created in `VS2010` with `VC++. Want to create the setup for this project. How it can be done so that all the other project are also included???

Comment: What are you using to create the setup project?

Comment: VS2010's add project.

Answer (score 1):

**To create a new setup project**

On the File menu, point to Add, then click New Project.

In the resulting Add New Project dialog box, in the Project Types pane, open the Other Project Types node, open Setup and Deployment Projects, and select Visual Studio Installer.

In the Templates pane, choose Setup Project for a standard setup, or Web Setup Project for a Web application.

**To add an existing setup project to a solution**

On the File menu, point to Add, then click Existing Project.

In the resulting Add Existing Project dialog box, browse to the location of the setup project and click Open.

Please check this link , This link has much more infromation 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project

Check this link as well
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z11b431t(v=vs.100).aspx